# Moving left brace in C code to the next line?

Tags: c, perl, sed, indentation

I have several C source files that need to have one particular formatting feature changed.  In some parts of the file,

```
if (x == NULL) {
    ...
}
```

needs to be changed to

```
if (x == NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

I was hoping to use the "indent" command, but it's far too aggressive.  It wants to change the entire file with all options.

I suppose I can do this in Perl or maybe even Sed, but I don't know either well enough to figure that out.

Comment: Well. Eclipse autoformatter can definitely do that with right settings. I would suspect other IDEs can as well. By the way, the first style is considered better for many major projects (like Linux, for example)

Comment: using `sed` will do it without having understanding of the `c` syntax. this may lead to further problem. `Indent` is safe option to use. Although one way is `sed ' /if/ s/{$/\n&/g'`   for all the lines having `if` statement or just `sed ' s/{$/\n&/g'` for all the lines. Make sure to keep a copy of the files before trying these commands.

Comment: The output of `indent` will be valid C code. You can't say the same about the output of any given `sed` or `perl` command. `indent` has a ton of options - some combination of them will do what you need assuming your code follows some set of conventions (which it should) and so all you need is to tell indent which conventions to follow for it to not modify the rest of your code that is already following those conventions.

Comment: You probably should not use sed for this purpose. C syntax could be tricky and obfuscated and you might miss certain cases.

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: @EdMorton "*The output of `indent` will be valid C code.*" Haha, no. `indent` doesn't really parse C either. You'll always have to manually check the results.

Comment: @melpomene can you give an example?

Comment: @EdMorton Pretty much any winner of the [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/years.html). One specific case I remember is that `indent` doesn't understand backslash-newline continuations.

Comment: @melpomene hmm, seems to handle backslash-newline continuations just fine for me (I just tested indent 2.2.11 with `printf \<newline>
("da\<newline>
rn\n");`). I guess I'll keep trusting it for now, especially if it only breaks for obfuscated code.

Comment: @EdMorton Try `prin\<newline>tf("...")`.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the example but seriously, if you write that then you deserve to have it break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like today is my lucky day, as it appears I figured it out:

```
sed 's/^\([ ]*\)\(if (.* == NULL)\) {$/\1\2\n\1{/g' <filename>
```

Can someone confirm that this is correct?

Comment: I can confirm it is not complete.

Comment: Run it. Try to compile.

Comment: I can also confirm it is not correct, nor can any variation of it ever be correct.

Comment: No, it produces the expected output given one specific sample input. That is the starting point for identifying a solution, not the end point. As **one trivial example** of input that it would not work for try `printf '// if (x == NULL) {\nif (x == 0) {\n' | sed 'script'` and it will generate C code that contains a syntax error (unmatched `{`).

Comment: Ok, if I change the expression to

    's/\^([ ]*\)\(if (.* == NULL)\) {$/\1\2\n\1{/g'

then that should make it more robust.

Comment: No. You cannot do this job robustly using sed or any other tool that doesn't understand the C language. Any expression you come up with there will be cases where it fails.

Comment: That might be fine for the OPs case though, as their code base is finite and the task is a one-time task.

Comment: @EugeneSh. We have no idea what the code base looks like or whether this is a one-off task or not or whether the code base today entirely encompasses what might be present in the code base the next time the OP (**or whoever is reading this question in future**) has to do this.

Comment: This is a one-off task.  I agree that my solution is limited, but a more generic solution would probably require using 'indent' and limiting its output in some way.

Comment: @lord_nimon You still have not told us why you need to do this.

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious?  I need to conform to the project's coding style.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with this?

```
$ cat tst.c
#include "stdio.h"

int
main ()
{
    void *x;

    if (x == NULL) {
        printf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ indent -i 4 -bli 0 -npcs -st tst.c
#include "stdio.h"

int
main()
{
    void *x;

    if (x == NULL)
    {
        printf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you have other examples of code segments that shouldn't be changed then create a sample program that includes those and tweak the `indent` options until you're happy that the style of code it's outputting is the style you want.

---

In a comment [@melpomene had mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399127/moving-left-brace-in-c-code-to-the-next-line/56399647#comment99397503_56399127) that `indent` doesn't always handle obfuscated code properly and gave the example of `prin\<newline>tf("...")`. idk about other cases but you can handle that one by pre-processing with the help of sed and gcc:

```
$ cat tst.c
#include "stdio.h"

int
main ()
{
    void *x;

    // here is a comment
    if (x == NULL) {
        prin\
tf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ indent -i 4 -bli 0 -npcs -st tst.c
#include "stdio.h"

int
main()
{
    void *x;

    // here is a comment
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        prin tf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ sed 's/a/aA/g;s/__/aB/g;s/#/aC/g' tst.c |
    gcc -CC -P -traditional-cpp -E - |
    sed 's/aC/#/g;s/aB/__/g;s/aA/a/g'
#include "stdio.h"

int
main ()
{
    void *x;

    // here is a comment
    if (x == NULL) {
        printf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ sed 's/a/aA/g;s/__/aB/g;s/#/aC/g' tst.c |
    gcc -CC -P -traditional-cpp -E - |
    sed 's/aC/#/g;s/aB/__/g;s/aA/a/g' |
    indent -i 4 -bli 0 -npcs -st
#include "stdio.h"

int
main()
{
    void *x;

    // here is a comment
    if (x == NULL)
    {
        printf("darn\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```